# Using global variables in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, global-variables

So, first question I couldn't find an answer to. Might be reason enough to ask my own first question. Apologies if the answer can be found outside the scope of backbone.js.

In a backbone.js app, I need to have access to several variables in different functions, so I have to use some global variables setup.

I'm wondering if my current solution is acceptable/good practise. My IDE (IDEA) seems to think it isn't:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

initialize:function(){
  var myGlobalVar, myOtherGlobalVar;//marked as unused local variable
},

myFunction:function() {          
      myGlobalVar = value;//marked as implicitly declared
      model.set({"mrJson": {"email": myGlobalVar}});
      model.save();
    });
  }
},

myOtherFunction:function() {          
      myOtherGlobalVar = otherValue;//marked as implicitly declared
      model.set({"mrJson": {"email": myGlobalVar, "other": myOtherGlobalVar}});
      model.save();
    });
  }
}
}
```

I tried declaring the implicitly declared globals, but that resulted in them not being accessible from the othe function.

Is there a proper way to do handle these global variables in backbone.js?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you are currently declaring the variables, they are in the function *initialize* scope, rather than then object *MyModel* scope. To define the variables as Model variables (accessible to all object functions) do:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

myGlobalVar: null,
myOtherGlobalVar: null,

initialize:function(){
  console.log(this.myGlobalVar)
},
...
```

Comment: I am facing a similar situation and while the above solution seems to be OK, my problem has to do more with the understanding of how the js parser works rather than how backbone works.I have made a jsbin NON-FUNCTIONAL code example(to make it functional the code will become compicated).Here is the link http://jsbin.com/tufeh/1/  When dropfrom is called  selestrt gets a value(it is a unix timestamp)...when changefrom is called(change event) though selestrt is undefined. What can I do in a situation like this? I hope you got the picture...